# A way to handle overflow in a dynamic system identification

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

I'm trying to use the scipy.optimize library in a system identification problem I'm working on. The goal is to find a vector of weights `w` that can simulate a single variable dynamic system as accurately as possible. I defined the function I'm trying to minimize, which in this case retuns the error of the identified simulation and the real system, schematically:

```
fQ(w): 
  simulatedOutput = simulate_system(); 
  e = realOutput-simulatedOutput
  return dot(e,e)
```

Since I'm trying to dynamically simulate a certain time period, there are certain configurations of the vector w for which the system is not stable and it diverges. The critical part of the code in the function `fQ(w)` is:

```
for i in range(0, nx):
                    for j in range(i, nx):
                        for l in range(j, nx):
                            colx[k, idx] = x[k, i] * x[k, j] * x[k, l]
                            idx += 1
```

Is there a way to handle this potential overflow? What I tried to do was

```
        idx = 0
        try :
            for i in range(0, nx):
                for j in range(i, nx):
                    for l in range(j, nx):
                        colx[k, idx] = x[k, i] * x[k, j] * x[k, l]
                        idx += 1
        except :
            print('ColX overflow, returning a large Q')
            return 10e40
```

which, technically, seems to be correct, since the real system does not diverge and this vector w is thus a wrong solution to the optimization problem.

My issues with this solution are following:

i) Using try try/catch structure anywhere other than handling errors is, to my knowledge, a very bad programming practice

ii) It doesn't seem to work right

My questions are:

Is there a proper way to implement this functionality? Is using a try/catch structure in instances like this permissible, assuming I know precisely what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a solution, which checks whether the vector values seem to be increasing over a reasonable value and return a large number in the optimization function.

```
        idx = 0
        for i in range(0, nx):
           for j in range(i, nx):
                colx[k, idx] = x[k, i] * x[k, j]
                if colx[k, idx] > 10e10:
                    print('ColX seems to diverge, returning a large Q')
                    return 10e10
                idx += 1
```

This seems to work well. Perhaps a smaller number than `10e10` would work well to increase the general speed of the optimization.